# Prolog equivalent for haskell concat

Tags: list, prolog, concatenation

I am trying to find an equivalent for haskell's `concat` in prolog.

For example lets have a list like this: `[[[a],[b]],[[c],[d]]]`.

And I need this list to be concatenated to a list like this `[[a,b],[c,d]]`.  So far I have tried some code with `append` but I could not think of a right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem using `flatten/2` and `append/3`, in this way:

```
my_concat([],L,L).
my_concat([H|T],LT,LO):-
    flatten(H,H1),
    append(LT,[H1],LT1),
    my_concat(T,LT1,LO).

?- my_concat([[[a],[b]],[[c],[d]]],[],L).
L = [[a, b], [c, d]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your example doesn't match the normal behavior of Haskell's `concat`:

```
Prelude> concat [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]
[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

To do what you want, you need to map `concat` over the individual lists inside the input list:

```
Prelude> map concat [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

In SWI-Prolog you have `append/2` (two arguments instead of the more common `append/3`'s three arguments) which corresponds to Haskell's `concat`:

```
?- append([[[a],[b]],[[c],[d]]], Flattened).
Flattened = [[a], [b], [c], [d]].
```

And also in SWI-Prolog there is a family of `maplist/N` predicates corresponding to Haskell's `map`:

```
?- maplist(append, [[[a],[b]],[[c],[d]]], FlattenedButDifferently).
FlattenedButDifferently = [[a, b], [c, d]].
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
my_concat([X], [FX]):-
   flatten(X,FX).

my_concat([H|T], [FH| FT]):-
   my_concat(T,FT),
   flatten(H,FH).
```